# Cannot print a form on Zebra printer

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to this. I'm using Visual Basic from Visual Studio 2017 Community, and I have an issue printing a form.

If i use this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    Me.PrintForm1.Print()
End Sub
```

on my regular printer it displays the form fine, but i needed to print the form on a label. When I change the printer to my Zebra printer, it does not display anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `When I change the printer to my Zebra printer, it does not display anything`, this is not easy to replicate. Have you tried printing other items other than your form, for example: a text file, pdf, word doc etc...

Comment: Is your model of Zebra printer displayed in Printers folder in Windows? I was working with some Zebra printers and they are not standard Windows printers, but devices that must be controlled directly via serial port. Printers like that can print only barcodes and simple text.